# Java - is it possible to apply setEditable(boolean b) to JSlider/

Tags: java, swing, jslider

in my program I need to disable my JSlider under certain circumstances, but do not know how. I tried setFocusable(false) but that did not work... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `setEnabled`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You change/restrict user interactions with the `JSlider` through the use of the `enabled` property.

[image: SliderState]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SliderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SliderTest();
    }

    public SliderTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JSlider slider = new JSlider();
                final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
                checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        slider.setEnabled(checkBox.isSelected());
                    }
                });
                checkBox.setSelected(true);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(slider, gbc);
                frame.add(checkBox, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the `setEnabled(boolean)` method. All `JComponents` inherit it by default.